# Inputting random integers into a file and sorting them into another file? FileIO

Tags: java, file, sorting

I'm trying to create a FileIO where random numbers are placed into a .txt file and outputted, sorted in another .txt file. I have a bubble sort code that can sort numbers & I have another code that makes a .txt file. I'm just not sure how I'd implement these 2 together.

Here's my fileIO code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    File file = new File("test.txt");

    //Writes name and age to the file

    try {
        PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(file);
        output.println("Rober");
        output.println(27);
        output.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.printf("ERROR: %s\n", ex);
    }

    //Reads from the file
    try {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(file);
        String name = input.nextLine();
        int age = input.nextInt();

        System.out.printf("Name: %s Age %d\n", name, age);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.printf("ERROR: %s\n", ex);
    }
}
```

And here is my bubble sort code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Random num = new Random();

    //Creating an array for 10 integers
    int [] number = new int [10];

    System.out.print("Random Numbers:");

    /*Display the unsorted numbers in a random order.
    These numbers range from 0 to 100
    */
    for (int d = 0 ; d<number.length ; d++){
        /* We add a "+1" to the nextInt(100) here because then the numbers
        will only range from 0 to 99.
        */
        int RandomG = num.nextInt(100)+1;
        number[d] = RandomG;
        System.out.print(" " +RandomG);
    }

    //Display the sorted numbers
    System.out.print("\nSorted Numbers:"+Arrays.toString(BubbleSortAsceMethod(number)));
}

public static int [] BubbleSortAsceMethod(int[] number){
    int placeholder;

    for(int i = 0 ; i < number.length-1 ; i++){
        for ( int x = 1 ; x < number.length-i ; x++){

            /*If the first number in the sequence is greater than the second
            number, than save the first number of sequence in placeholder 
            and place the second number in the first numbers position, and 
            put the placeholder in the second numbers position (SWAP).
            */

            /*
             Since this is saying that when the first term is bigger than the
            2nd term, the sequence will increase. If we flip the relational
            operator, the sequence will decrease.
            */

            if ( number[x-1] < number[x]){ 
                placeholder = number[x-1];
                number[x-1] = number[x];
                number[x] = placeholder;
            }
        }
    }
    return number;
}
```

I'm kinda new to all this java stuff so please go a bit easy on me! Any help at all is appreciated :)

Comment: Is generating data, writing to a file, read in the file before sorting and writing to another file the requirement? You may be better of generating the data, sorting it then writing it once.

Answer (score 0):

As the data contained in the file will consist of a pair of values: The name (String) and the age (int), you will need to retain their relationship. The best way of doing this would be to create a Class to represent the data. Eventually you want to sort the data on age using your BubbleSort method. While practically this would not be your first choice to sort data, I assume that this is a requirement. The BubbleSort method you have sorts an `int[]` by comparing each entry against it's immediate neighbor. With `int` being primitive, you can directly compare each element using the `<` operator.

```
public class Person implements Comparable<Person> {
    private String name;
    private int age;
    public Person(String name, int age) {
       this.age = age;
       this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() { return name; }
    public int getAge() { return age; }

    @Override
    public String toString() { 
        return name + System.lineSeperator() + age; 
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Person person) {
        return this.age - person.age;
    }
}
```

You may want to implement the [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface to compare Objects; in which the interface must be implemented by Overriding the `compareTo(Person person)` method. You can impose sorting on age by returning the difference in age. This is not the only way you can impose the order you want; you may wish to compare directly using the `getAge()` of each Object or create a [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) object.

Using the `Comparable` interface does allow you to make your `BubbleSort` class more generic, however (though the array must be of Objects that implement the interface; hence no primitive types).

```
public class BubbleSort {
    public static <T extends Comparable> T[] BubbleSortAsceMethod(T[] array) {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
            for (int x = 1; x < array.length - i; x++) {
                if (comparator.compare(array[x - 1], array[x]) < 0) {
                    T placeholder = array[x - 1];
                    array[x - 1] = array[x];
                    array[x] = placeholder;
                }
            }
        }
        return array;
    }
}
```

You will notice that this sort method has some slight differences from your original, namely the `BubbleSortAsceMethod` method signature with the introduction of [generic type parameters](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/methods.html). Once again, this is **completely** optional, though this does give you the flexibility to use this method in the future for other arrays of Classes that extend the Comparable interface.

If you don't want to use generics or the `Comparable` interface, you will need to change the method signature and if statement.
You're method signature should instead look like `public static Person[] BubbleSortAsceMethod(Person[] array)` and the if statement `if (array[x-1].getAge() < array[x].getAge())`

This can give you an illustration of it working, though this does not consider the file io which should be simple to implement from what you have done already.

```
static Random random = new Random();

public static void main (String args[]) {
    int size = 100;
    Person[] peopleArray = new Person[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        String name = generateName(random.nextInt(4) + 4);
        int age = random.nextInt(100);
        peopleArray[i] = new Person(name, age);
    }
    peopleArray = BubbleSort.BubbleSortAsceMethod(peopleArray);
}
```

**Note** that this conforms, at least as much as possible, to the code you have implemented this far. If the BubbleSort and use of arrays are not critical, data structures that implement the [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) interface, such as [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/management/AttributeList.html), can allow you to implement this much cleaner. This does not use the BubbleSort method at all.

```
public static void main (String args[]) {
    int size = 100;
    ArrayList<Person> people = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
       String name = generateName(random.nextInt(4) + 4);
       int age = random.nextInt(100);
       people.add(new Person(name, age));
    }
    peopleList.sort(Person::compareTo);
    //or, if you don't want to implement comparable
    peopleList.sort(Comparator.comparing(Person::getAge));
}
```

Appendix:

Used for illustrative purposes: Generates a name of a set length (randomly).

```
static char[] alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".toCharArray();

public static String generateName(int length) {
    if (length > 0) {
        return alphabet[random.nextInt(alphabet.length)] + generateName(length - 1);
    }
    return "";
}
```